# ULN2803 switch off

Tags: switching, uln2803

I have a ULN2803 that drives a higher current H-Bridge but the issue is the ULN2803 is inverting the output. I was thinking of switching the ULN2803 off until the micro-controller is ready to take over but I'm not sure how to go about it.

For reference here is the circuit I'm building:
[image]

I was thinking about putting a transistor on the GND pin of the ULN2803 but could not get it to work.

Comment: Can you use a 74LS266?  XNOR instead?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any 74266 at hand. Nevertheless even if I used a XNOR TTL there would still be half of the outputs high on the ULN2803.

Comment: *"the issue is the ULN2803 is inverting the output"*  Based on this, inverting the input would solve it.  If you have more conditions you need satisfied please update the question.

Comment: I don't understand how it would solve it since half of the output would still be inverting.